# Cant Consume Json Object In Ionic Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, ionic-framework

I have been facing some difficulty in accessing a json object returned from my node.js server
in my Ionic Application.

The following is my code:
HTML Code:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="msg in messages">
    <div class="section-a">{{ msg.text }}</div>
    <div class="section-b">{{ msg.info }}</div>
</ion-item>
```

My Controller:

```
// some vars
var db = this;
db.messages = [];

SystemData.getMessages( some_user_id ).then( function( res ) {
    // the above SystemData is my service ...

    if ( res.data != 0 || res.data != null ) {
        for ( var i = 0; i < res.data.length; i++ ) {
            var msgObj = {
                text: res.data[i].Messages,
                now: res.data[i].Info
            };

            db.messages.push( msgObj );

            $scope.messages = db.messages;
        }
    }
})
```

The following code doesnt return anything in the view section. Although since the divs in the ion-item tag is styled,
i could see the divs but with no data. Actually there exists two results and this displays two divs but with no data.
Below is a snapshot of my console on the return json data.

[image: Console Img]

Comment: Sorry the above variable declarations was just messed up before i clicked the post question. This is the right code : var db = this; db.messages = [];

Comment: I just removed the back slashes that got injected into the code some places, appears okay now.

Comment: the `$scope.messages = db.messages` should be outside the loop, also show us what is in the expanded objects in the response, we can't see if the properties match what you have in the view.  You can also use `{{msg|json}}` to see what properties the objects contain within your ng-repeat.